# Getting checked radio buttons values

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm having a small problem trying to get the checked values from a radio group.

I've used a for loop to create my questions and radiogroups.

```
 LinearLayout a = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.aLayout);
        for (int k = 1; k < 11; k++){
        //CREATE QUESTIONS
        TextView q = new TextView(this);
        q.setText(k + ")" + " " + pssQ[k]);
        a.addView(q);
        //CREATE RADIO BUTTONS
        final RadioButton[] rB = new  RadioButton[5];
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(this);
        rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
                rB[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                rg.addView(rB[i]);
                rB[i].setText(a1[i]);
            }
        a.addView(rg);
            //get values here??
    }
```

The code works how I intended it to.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the checked radio-button from each iteration. There is ten in total that I want to collect.

Any guidance would be appreciated. And if there's an easier alternative I'd be open to suggestions.

Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach a check change listener to each of your `RadioGroup` within the loop:

```
    rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // your logic here
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

A way will be to use an additional variable (for example) `isChecked` as a boolean variable ,so when `isChecked` is true you will can spot which radio button is checked by the user on any iteration.